# Limited Access - 'Given directly' missing for a user. User not able to view Site pages properly

Tags: permissions

We are facing a strange issue with one of our Intranet users. He is not able to view pages as expected.
[image]

On analyzing his permissions noticed that specifically for this user 'Limited Access' 'Given Directly' is missing in permissions list. Which is available for all other users.

[image]

Have been searching the net for this. What i come to know is that limited access permission is given automatically by SharePoint (can't be given by Admins / users).

Comment: Correct, Limited access can't be given by Admins/Users, It manage by SharePoint. For example if you stop inherit on list and set read permission for TestUser, so in parent like for web level permission SharePoint assign limited access.
For not view site pages properly could you check user has permission to access external CSS/JS.

Comment: Hi Bharat, thank you for the reply. I checked permissions on Style Library and user has Read.Limited Access permissions on it as shown above (for root site level). Not able to make out why user not able to see page properly when he has Read, Limited Access permissions through mutltiple means.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the Limited Access permission is assigned to a user automatically by SharePoint when you give permission to the user to access a specific content item. But the user does not have permission to open or edit any other items in the library.

You cannot assign this permission level to users or SharePoint groups. Instead, Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 automatically assigns this permission level to users and SharePoint groups when you grant them access to an object on your site that requires that they have access to a higher level object on which they do not have permissions. For example, if you grant users access to an item in a list and they do not have access to the list itself, Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 automatically grants them Limited Access on the list, and also the site, if needed.

So, in order to fix the above issue, you need to give at least "Read" permissions to that user so that they can access the page.

[Reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-limited-access/062eedd0-d996-4bd1-8d2b-c01c5f4e6357)

Comment: Hi Sohail, Thank you for the reply. As per the snap shot user has Read. Limited Access permissions through multiple means. Is it that am missing something.

Comment: As the user already has Read permissions, the issue seems might be due to that particular page (in screenshot or master page if it is whole site) is not published by the user and so the unexpected changes is visible only to that user and not others.